# How to Properly Set Up If in While Loop

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, while-loop, scripting

I'm going to add the rest of the functionality to the program later it's still in it's early stages, but I cant seem to get out of the while loop for some reason even though the if statement is within it and under the menu. Here's the code so far.

````
continue="true"

#while loop to keep the code running till the user inputs Q
while [ $continue = "true" ] 

#loop start
do
        #clearing screen before showing the menu
        clear
        echo "A to Create a user account"
        echo "B to Delete a user account"
        echo "C to Change Supplementary Group for a user account"
        echo "D to Create a user account"
        echo "E to Delete a user account"
        echo "F to Change Supplementary Group for a user account"
        echo "Q to Quit"
        read -p "What would you like to do?:" choice

        #Test to end the program
        if [ $choice = 'Q' ] || [ $choice = 'q']
                then
                $continue="false"
        fi
#loop end
done```
````

Comment: `break` is what you're looking for. `help break` for more info. Also you don't need the `[ ]` or any test if an infinite loop is what you're after, here `while true; do...; done` or `while :; do ....; done` see `help :`

Comment: for my assignment I'm not allowed to exit the while loop with an exit or a break statement

Comment: Great!,  have fun then.

Comment: `$continue=false` is a syntax error. You're not allowed to have a`$` at the left hand side of the assignment. Put a shebang and paste  your code at https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, not to *set* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pointed out by Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822725/how-to-properly-set-up-if-in-while-loop#comment118121400_66822725), you need `continue="false"` not `$continue="false"`.

Also, I advise using `if [ "$choice" = 'Q' ] || [ "$choice" = 'q' ]` so your script won't break if the user hits CR and did not enter anything.  (Also note that you need a space before last `]` in that statement.)

Answer (score 0):

Although the syntax error has already been highlighted in the comments, I would suggest avoiding the `continue` variable entirely by using `break`. And you can also combine the two checks using a regex. Something like this

```sh
while true; do
    read -p "What would you like to do?: " choice
    if [[ "$choice" =~ [Q|q] ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Though when I look at the echo statements in your question it seems like you would probably be better off avoiding the if entirely, and instead use a case statement

```sh
while true; do 
    read -p "What would you like to do?: " choice
    case "$choice" in
        q|Q) break 
            ;; 
        a|A) echo "Creating a user account"
            ;;
        #This catches anything else
        *) echo "unknown option"
            ;; 
    esac 
done
```